# How can I suppress cascade on the initial load of jsTree?

Tags: jstree

I'm using jsTree with the checkbox plugin. I have the cascade set to "down". This works great, except that when I want to load data with a mixture of checked and unchecked nodes, the cascade overrides the "state" setting for nodes. E.g.

```
var data = [
    {"id":"p90","parent":"#","text":"Page1", "state": { "selected": true} },
    {"id":"p100","parent":"p90","text":"Page2", "state": { "selected": true} },
    {"id":"p101","parent":"p100","text":"Page3", "state": { "selected": false} },
    {"id":"p102","parent":"p101","text":"Page4", "state": { "selected": true} },
    {"id":"p103","parent":"p101","text":"Page5", "state": { "selected": false} }
];

$(function () {
    $("#PageTree")
        .jstree({
            core: { data: data },
            plugins: ["checkbox"],
            checkbox: { cascade: "down", three_state: false },
            expand_selected_onload: true
        });
});
```

This results in this:

[image: all checked]

But it should look like this:

[image: some checked]

I tried setting the "cascade" setting after the tree is loaded, but that didn't work. It seems like the only option will be to write my own cascade code, but I'm looking for a slicker option.

Comment: For anyone coming here with other issues of event suppression on initial load of the tree, please check out https://www.jstree.com/api/#/?q=refresh&f=refresh() for info on how to use the refresh event if you use it manually. I didn't look closely enough at the parameters like `forget_state` and it caused me a lot of trouble...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing, which is the solution recommended by the developer of jsTree (https://github.com/vakata/jstree/issues/774):

```
$("#PageTree")
    .on('select_node.jstree', function (e, data) {
        if (data.event) {
            data.instance.select_node(data.node.children_d);
        }
    })
    .on('deselect_node.jstree', function (e, data) {
        if (data.event) {
            data.instance.deselect_node(data.node.children_d);
        }
    })
    .jstree({
        core: { data: pages },
        plugins: ["checkbox"],
        checkbox: { cascade: "", three_state: false },
        expand_selected_onload: true
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's my solution, if you instancied cascade like this, this should use the native cascade function after init and won't make any performance problems.

```
$tree.on('init.jstree', function(e, data) {
    data.instance.settings.checkbox.cascade = '';
}).jstree({
    core: {
        multiple: true,
        check_callback: true,
        data: {'Your own data'},
    },
    checkbox: {
        three_state: false,
        cascade: 'down'
    },
    plugins: [your own list]
}).on('loaded.jstree', function() {
    $tree.jstree(true).settings.checkbox.cascade = 'down';
})
```